# Update field with result of DateDiff of two other populated fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

All I need to do is take two datetime fields and set a third field to its result.

This has to be easy but I've been working on it for 2 days and cannot get the result I'm looking for.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME) or die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

$helpme=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE chat_main SET Exact_Time = DATEDIFF(Start_TimeStamp, End_TimeStamp)");

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: What you should fetch from an `update` query?

Comment: `$helpme` is the result of an UPDATE query. It does not return a result. So, you cannot use `mysql_fetch_array` to get a result. If your query was a SELECT, you could get a result.

Comment: Alright, so you are saying, use the select, then do fetch, then update table with result?

Comment: Yes. After the UPDATE, you use: `$helpme = mysqliquery($con, "SELECT Exact_Time from chat_main");` and then fetch a result. Of course, you should check to see if you get an error from the UPDATE or the SELECT. If there is an error, you can't fetch anything.

Comment: I will try it now.  Just looks backwards, since the datediff calculation seems like it should first so there is something to update the db with.

Comment: The UPDATE query you already have is updating the database. Everything after that is not necessary to update the database. The echo is just so you can see the new values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning problem: expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077263/warning-problem-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result)

Comment: I understand...It isn't updating the database though and I'm not receiving an error.  All three fields are datetime - could this be the issue?  I've tried changing that also and still no updating database.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`. Plus, you may need a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Fred-ii- already have that on the page, nothing shows and no update in db.

Comment: I edited my comment. Try using a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: but the thing is, that syntax for the `while`, is for SELECT, not update. that's why you're getting that error. so just remove the `while` and use `mysqli_affected_rows()` in a conditional, or just nothing at all and check using `mysqli_error()`. you have a few choices to check for success/fail.

Comment: @Lori The DATEDIFF function returns an integer (the number of days between the two dates). It looks like your two fields are on the same day, so DATEDIFF will likely return 0. I think you want TIMEDIFF.

Comment: Please see edits above.  That portion is removed and I'm just dealing with the update statement.  It isn't updating with or without WHERE and I'm receiving zero errors with the error reporting on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that DATEDIFF returns the number of days between two dates. It appears that in the context of your implementation, the two dates are on the same day. So, you always get 0 as a result of DATEDIFF. I suggest using TIMEDIFF, which will be the difference of the two times, not the two dates.

Answer (score 2):

This question should really be answered. I'll remove the answer if someone else adds a better answer.

The `DATEDIFF` function operates on the "date" portion of the `DATETIME` only, and returns an integer number of days.

To get the difference between two DATETIME values as a number of seconds, you can use the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function.

To get the difference returned as a `TIME` value, you can use `TIMEDIFF` function.

---

This begs the question why you would need to store this, since this expression can be evaluated in a SELECT statement. (One good reason for storing it is you want to add an index on it, and MySQL doesn't support function based indexes.)

---

And, an `UPDATE` statement does not return a resultset, so you can't fetch rows from it like you would from a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks @Spencer7593.  I understand all of this, I was only fetching the rows to see the info for testing purposes.  The timediff is a crucial part of the project I'm working on and I require that it is stored.  No other reason.